# Why is my datetime object being converted to a string?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a class with a public attribute created_at, that will stored the date of a current time, but when I check what type of object it is i says it is a string:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Instantiation Method"""
    if not kwargs:
        self.id = uuid4()
        self.created_at = datetime.now().isoformat()
        self.updated_at = datetime.now().isoformat()
```

When I check what type of object it i I get the following:

```
t = Model()
print(type(t.created_at))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

It should be a datetime object but it says it is a string, is it because of the `isoformat()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `isoformat()` return string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `.isoformat()` that convert the date to str:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Instantiation Method"""
        if not kwargs:
            self.created_at = datetime.utcnow()
        
t = Model()
print(type(t.created_at))
```

Output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```